# Why do we use a parent class reference to a child class instance?

Tags: class, inheritance, interface, instantiation

I'm learning Java from ebooks etc and quite a few times I have come across something like this:

**Example 1.**

```
public interface TravelOptions()
{
    ...
}

public class Hovercraft implements TravelOptions
{
    ...
}

Main()
{
    TravelOptions speedy = new Hovercraft();

    ...
}
```

**Example 2.**

```
public class Animal
{
    ...
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    ...
}

Main()
{
    Animal Husky = new Dog();

    ...
}
```

My question is why do we bother assigning reference variable from another type say an Interface or a Superclass? Doesn't assigning to the original class instantion do the trick? What is the rationale behind all these?

Just to be more specific. Why not do these?

```
Hovercraft speedy = new Hovercraft();
```

or

```
Dog husky = new Dog();
```

Thanks in advance!